# Age of Ultron #9 - Wolverine's weakness?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine

In the latest AU issue, where both wolverines are faced with the choice of deciding which one goes back to the 'original' time line with Sue Storm...im just not exactly sure what happened in those panels...did the one wolverine kill the other at his request with the reasoning being that he just couldn't live with being responsible for pym's death and the resulting defeat of the defenders?

So does that mean that wolverine can actually be killed by a blade?

[image]

Comment: I was going to ask just the same question.

Answer (score 3):

It's fairly clear that the idea is that one Wolverine ***has*** killed the other. The "twist" from the cover shot (showing what *appears* to be two Logans fighting) is that it was actually voluntary.

We know from past comics that Logan can regenerate from appalling damage, up to and including his whole body being blown apart but we also know that damage to his brain is irreversible, something that was a key point in the film X-Men Origins: Wolverine.

[image: Logan nuke]

It follows that if one Logan could somehow cause massive damage to his alter's heart **and** brain you'd stand a fair chance of killing them, or at the very least leaving them a complete vegetable.

[image: Logan shot in head]

Comment: Curb Stomp - GOW style?